# How to select an element among others all having same css value in webdriver?

Tags: webdriver

I have a tree structure, which has expandable icons but all having same Css value. My objective is to parse through different rows and once i found a desired element, i will click on the expandable icon associated to it..

I am able to parse the tree and reach the desired element. But whenever i tried to click on the expandable image icon [let say 4th icon] using css value, it always select the 1st icon

Comment: What is the css locator you are using?

Answer (score 0):

You could use GetElements instead of GetElement and then iterate through the collection, but it seems this could be solved more easily with a CSS selector using nth-child: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp